# Is it possible to replicate this exact jpg image?

Tags: tikz-trees

My question is about creating this exact tree in latex.

i am trying several methods, but with no results..

[image: tree]

my code is as below

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twosided]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=9em,
every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20}]]
\node {Numri i firmave ?}[a]
child { node {1 firm\"e} 
    child { node {} 
        child {node{monopol}}}}
child { node {Pak firma} 
    child {node {}
        child {node {oligopol}}}
}
child { node {Shum\"e firma}
    child { node {lloji i produktit}
        child{node {konk monop}}
        child{node {konk e plt}
}}};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) not really a problem with normal tikz. But this site is not a _please do this for me_ service. Please ask a specific question related to LaTeX and friends. The image can easily be created using nodes and lines between node or point on the edges of nodes. See for example http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/ for some inspiration. As far as I know there is a two part node type as well.

Comment: Yes. It’s possible. Provide a MWE of what you have tried so far so that someone here can help you finish it.

Comment: @daleif thank you for your warm welcome.. I actually know that this is not "please do this for me service"..

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code to it

Comment: I don't know how to write on the arrows

Comment: @KlodiGj, please move your code to question (by editing it)

Answer (score 1):

Your MWE is not exactly like your figure, I followed the former.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twosided]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    sibling distance=10em,
    mynode/.style = {
            shape=rectangle,         rounded corners,
            draw, align=center,
            top color=white, bottom color=blue!20
            },
    myquest/.style = {shape=rectangle,        draw, align=center,
        fill=blue!20},
    ]
    \node[myquest] {Numri i firmave ?}
        child { node[mynode, yshift=-4em] (monop) {monopol}
            edge from parent
                node[left=16pt] {1 firm\"e} 
            }
        child {node[mynode, right=of monop] (olig){oligopol} edge from parent node[right] {Pak firma}}
        child {  
        node[myquest] {lloji i produktit}
            child{node[mynode, right=of olig] (monocomp) {konk monop}}
            child{node[mynode, right=of monocomp] {konk e plt}}
        edge from parent node[above right] {Shum\"e firma}
     };
\end{tikzpicture}    
\caption{A figure from your MWE}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]